# Name output file by taking cin by the user

Tags: c++

Following is the code to have output file. What if I want to give this output file different name each time, i.e., as demanded by the user. What kind of getline command would help.
I know I can simply cin a string name my_file but the desired name is in the input not in the string name.

```
void save(cdStruct *ptr)    //Function that saves database info to file

        {

            ofstream dataFile;

            dataFile.open("output.txt", ios::out | ios::app);

            dataFile << ptr->title << endl;

            dataFile << ptr->artist << endl;
            dataFile << ptr->numberOfSongs << endl;

            dataFile << ptr->number << endl;

            dataFile.close();

        }
```

Comment: you have to be much more specific than this.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @Default I mean every time, programme runs, it should ask the user for the name of the file. then this file should be saved with that name.

Comment: @emartel I tried getline(cin, input) but it did not work.

Comment: What does "it did not work" mean?

Comment: You can't just simply take an input by getline(cin, my_file);
and then writing
datafile.open(my_file,ios::out | ios::app)

Answer (score 1):

You want to change this line:

> dataFile.open("output.txt", ios::out | ios::app);

To something like this??

> dataFile.open(my_name_string, ios::out | ios::app);

If yes, you have only to read this string before, add ".txt" and it's everything.

Check this code:

> string name;
>   cin >name;
>
> name.append(".txt");
>
> ofstream dataFile;
>   dataFile.open(name.c_str(), ios::out | ios::app);
>   dataFile.close();

Comment: My_file name is a string. Now cin this input.
the desired name is in the input not in the string name.

Comment: You can get rid of that awful `new` and `strcpy` code and simply do `dataFile.open(name.c_str(), ios::app)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your specific problem is not **"Give output file desired name as desired by the user"**, but **"How to read user input in command line program"**. For this, you can use `std::getline`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::string filename;
    getline(std::cin, filename);
}
```

One could be tempted to use the `operator<<` overloads,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main () {
     std::string filename;
     std::cin >> filename;
}
```

however, they would give wrong results if your filename contains whitespace characters.

---

Sidenote: Don't pass nullable pointers when you want to enforce non-null values:

```
// don't: void save(cdStruct *ptr)
void save(cdStruct const &ptr) // <- ah, better
```

Comment: You mean something like that:
getline(cin, file_name);

Comment: data.file(file_name,ios::out | ios::app)

Comment: @AzkaAhmad: That's exactly what I wrote. What do you want to explain to me?

Comment: When you run into an error, it often helps a lot to provide the error message and what you did to produce it. So far we know absolutely nothing about that.

Comment: These are the errors....
void std::basic_ofstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char
no matching function for call to âstd::basic_ofstream<char>::open(std::string&, std::_Ios_Openmode)â

Comment: @Terrenium: Are you missing a `#include <string>`?

Comment: No this string is being included

Comment: @Terrenium: Please copy+paste some code that demonstrates how it doesn't work. Otherwise I can only provide more wild guesses.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments on other answers it sounds like you are passing the file name as a `std::string` to `std::ofstream::open`. Before `C++11` it only accepted a `const char *` parameter, not a `std::string` (see [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open)).

To fix this use `filename.c_str()` as the first parameter instead of `filename`. This returns a null-terminated char array, the type expected by `std::ofstream::open`

Answer (score 0):

Your error message tells the following: you are using `std::string` at some point when you should be using `char const *`. Now we only need to find the proper place where the error occurs.

A quick look into online documentation of [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) tells us, that this function is not the problem: the signature allows `std::string`. The only other thing that has changed is the `std::ofstream(filename, std::ios::out | std::ios::ate)`, so we check the documentation of [`std::ofstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ofstream/open/); indeed a `char const *`.

This problem should be quickly solved by replacing

```
std::ofstream dataFile(filename, std::ios::out | std::ios::ate);
```

with

```
std::ofstream dataFile(filename.data(), std::ios::out | std::ios::ate);
```

and then it should compile.

It is very important that you try to understand the error messages that your compiler is giving you and search for references where the problem may lie.

Comment: You should use `c_str()` instead of `data()` if you want a null-terminated `C` string. The site you referenced is also outdated, `C++11` added an `ofstream::open` overload that accepts a `std::string` parameter.